# i can't change label text from different classes

Tags: java

I added two labels ,jLabel1 and jLabel2 to main frame, and I created one class with the name of language.java now am trying to change the text of these two labels, jLabel1 and jLabel2 from this class language.java but its giving error. here is the my code

```
public class lang {

    void urdu(){
        jLabel.setText="udru1";    
        jLabe2.setText="udru2";       
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's your error message? Can you show us the first class?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints very carefully, and be aware that if you ask lots of questions of low quality, you will be automatically banned from asking more until you have improved the existing ones.

Comment: this error cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable jLabel
  location: class lang

Comment: First of all, you should use setText("udru1"), not setText="udru1"

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class, add data members to place your labels there, add a modify method with parameters will be better. Additionally, ths setText is a method with String parameter that will be used to change the label's text. So it'll be something like this

```
public class lang {
    private jLabel lbl1;
    private jLabel lbl2;
    public lang(jLabel lbl1, jLabel lbl2){
        this.lbl1 = lbl1;
        this.lbl2 = lbl2;
    }

    public void urdu(){
        lbl1.setText("udru1");    
        lbl2.setText("udru2");       
    }
    //modify method
    public void modify(String txtLabel1, String txtLabel2){
        lbl1.setText(txtLabel1);
        lbl2.setText(txtLabel2);
    }
 }
```